# use ggplot to plot a panel of bar plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame which reads as below:

```
      factor bin          ret
1       beta   1 -0.026840807
2       beta   2 -0.051610137
3       beta   3 -0.044658901
4       beta   4 -0.053322048
5       beta   5 -0.060173704
6       size   1 -0.047448288
7       size   2 -0.045603776
8       size   3 -0.051804757
9       size   4 -0.047044614
10      size   5 -0.045720971
11 liquidity   1 -0.057657070
12 liquidity   2 -0.053105474
13 liquidity   3 -0.045501401
14 liquidity   4 -0.048572585
15 liquidity   5 -0.032209038
16 nonlinear   1 -0.045752503
17 nonlinear   2 -0.047673201
18 nonlinear   3 -0.051107792
19 nonlinear   4 -0.045364070
20 nonlinear   5 -0.047722148
21      btop   1 -0.004399745
22      btop   2 -0.035082069
23      btop   3 -0.054526058
24      btop   4 -0.063497535
25      btop   5 -0.077123859
```

I would like to plot a panel of charts which looks similar to this:
[image]

The difference is that the chart I would like to create would have the bin as the x- axis, and ret as the y- axis. And charts should be bar plot. Anyone could help me with this question?

FYI: The code for the sample plot I've included is:

```
print(ggplot(df, aes(date,value)) +ylab('return(bps)') + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ series,ncol=input$numCol)+theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, colour = "red", angle = 0)))
```

I wonder if minor change to the code could solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you're description i'll assume this is what you're after

```
print(ggplot(df, aes(bin, ret)) +
    ylab('return(bps)')  +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    facet_wrap(~ factor,ncol=2)+
    theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, colour = "red", angle = 0)))
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, MrFlick. This is exactly what I wanted. Is it possible to alter the color of the bars and add the x labels to each of the charts?

Comment: @user2854008 yes. you can set `fill=` or `color=` in the `geom_bar`